# Find numbers that are in parentheses using regular expression and Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

There is such line

`let str = 'ds 1,2abc{3,4}dd'`

I need to find numbers that will be included in {} without enclosing the brackets themselves.

For example (Assuming that `regex` is a per-defined regular expression) I want to write something like the following.

`(str.match(regexp)).join('').split(',')`

Which will produce a result like this => `['3','4']`

and if I have only one char in brackets or char with comma I need to get next result

`let str = 'ds 1,2abc{3,}dd'`

`(str.match(regexp)).join('').split(',')` => `['3','']`

At the moment, I have such a regular `const regexp = (/\d+\,\d*|(?<=\{)\d+/`
but it does not handle the case when there are more numbers in the string with a comma like 1,2

Comment: A usual quick way to extract them looks like `str.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[^{}]*})/g)`. Or, with `/\d*\.?\d+(?=[^{}]*})/g`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are actually trying to include an empty string in your resulting array. Maybe you could use:

```js
var str = 'ds 1,2abc{3,4}dd';
var res = str.split(/[{}]/)[1].split(",");
console.log(res)
```

---

```js
var str = 'ds 1,2abc{3,}dd';
var res = str.split(/[{}]/)[1].split(",");
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual workaround, when the number of open/close curly braces is matching and you need not pre-validate your input, you may simply use

```
str.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[^{}]*})/g)
str.match(/\d*\.?\d+(?=[^{}]*})/g)
```

Here, `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[^{}]*})` matches 1+ digits, followed with an optional sequence of a dot and 1+ digits followed with 0 or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}`.

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/HK4soe/3)

In a more generic case, you may extract groups of numbers inside curly braces by matching curly braces with comma-separated numbers in them first. Then, you may extract the numbers from each match:

```js
const str = 'ds 1,2abc{3,4}dd{not this one 5,6} and {7,8.666,9,10.45}';
const rx = /{\d*\.?\d+(?:,\d*\.?\d+)*}/g;
const results = str.match(rx).map(x => x.replace(/[{}]+/g,'').split(','));
console.log( results );
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HK4soe/1).

- `{` - a `{` char
- `\d*\.?\d+` - 0 or more digits followed with an optional `.` and then 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d*\.?\d+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of a comma followed with 0 or more digits followed with an optional `.` and then 1+ digits
- `}` - a `{` char.